# I can't seem to remove this weird code on my WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

I am designing a WordPress for a client, and just out of the blue, I see this code popup and can't seem to remove it

I am using WordPress and everything here is a free plugin (nothing is nulled), whenever I remove the Row, this keeps popping up and I cannot seem to remove it, my Wordfence security plugin did detect this at one point before, but yet, I still cannot get this weird code to dissappear, hope I can get some help on removing this part, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your Active theme's index.php and functions.php file. might be there is extra code added by any Virus Attacks. Mostly In any of the your theme file have extra code out of php tag which print this.